# Trying to create new instance of class using template, unexpected error

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, binary-search-tree

Trying to make a **B** inary **S** earch **T** ree (BST for short) using a template.

When I try to create a new instance of my BST I get an unexpected error. I hope the solution does not involve pointers since I would like to keep them at a minimum.

For now I have:

```
template <typename Type>
class BST {                 // The binary search tree containing nodes
private:
    BSTNode<Type> *root;    // Has reference to root node

public:
    BST ();
    bool add (int, Type);
};
```

And the Node type:

**EDIT:** When I cut out code to un-encumber text, I forgot the constructor, now it's been added

```
template <typename Type>
class BSTNode {    // Binary Search Tree nodes
private:
    int key;       // we search by key, no matter what type of data we have
    Type data;
    BSTNode *left;
    BSTNode *right;

public:
    BSTNode (int, Type&); 
    bool add (int, Type);
};
```

**EDIT2:** Here is the actual constructor

```
template <typename Type>
BSTNode<Type>::BSTNode (int initKey, Type &initData) {
     this->key = initKey;
     this->data = initData;
     this->left = NULL;
     this->right = NULL;
}
```

I want to try and test if anything works / doesn't work

```
BSTNode<int> data = new BSTNode (key, 10);
```

And I get: Expected type specifier before BSTNode. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but one thing I do hope is I don't have to use data as a pointer.

```
BSTNode<int> data = new BSTNode<int> (key, 10);
```

Also does not work, seems it believes `< int >` is `< & int>`  and it doesn't match

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to fully specify the type on the RHS of the assignment, and, since you are instantiating a dynamically allocated node with `new`, the LHS should be a pointer:

```
BSTNode<int>* data = new BSTNode<int> (key, 10);
            ^                     ^
```

If you don't need a node pointer, then use

```
BSTNode<int> data(key, 10);
```

Second, your `BSTNode<T>` class doesn't have a constructor taking an int and a `Type`, so you need to provide that too.

```
template <typename Type>
class BSTNode {
 public:
  BSTNode(int k, const Type& val) : key(k), data(val), left(0), right(0) { .... }
};
```

Comment: Forgot to paste it in, here it is now, is it wrong in any way ?

Comment: @Kalec the constructor is OK, but better use the initializer list to avoid unnecessary default initializations/assignments.

Comment: @Kalec and you probably don't want to pass `Type` by value in the constructor.

Comment: Ok, but I still have the same problem, as in the constructor was already there so it changes nothing. I have no idea why I get the compiling error.

Comment: @Kalec for the reason I give at the top of the answer?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'BSTNode<int>::BSTNode(int **&** , int)'|

Comment: @Kalec try **const** reference for `Type` in the constructor.

Comment: conversion from 'BSTNode<int>*' to non-scalar type 'BSTNode<int>' requested

Comment: @Kalec I had missed another error in your code, see updated answer.

Comment: Ok, this solved the problem, now I have a similar one in the add function but I'll ask another question rather than encumber this one. Thank you!