# Linked List Queue template argument list error

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to build a queue ADT using nodes; however, I received two errors: C2955 ('QueueNode': use of class template requires template argument list) & C2514 ('QueueNode': class has no constructors). I don't understand why I'm getting these errors. I've added the template argument list and I've created a constructor for QueueNode class. Have I missed something? The code for the linked queue and node are written below, as well as the main. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Queue.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
template<class ItemType>
class QueueNode
{
public:
    QueueNode();
    int key;
    QueueNode<ItemType>* next;
};

template<class ItemType>
inline QueueNode<ItemType>::QueueNode() :key(0), next(NULL)
{}
```

LinkedQueue.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "QueueNode.h"
#include <iostream>
template<class ItemType>
class LinkedQueue : public QueueNode<ItemType>
{
private:
    QueueNode<ItemType>* frontOfQueue = NULL;
    QueueNode<ItemType>* backOfQueue = NULL;
public:
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void enqueue(int key);
    void dequeue();
    void peekFront();
    void displayQueue();
};

template<class ItemType>
inline bool LinkedQueue<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    if (frontOfQueue == NULL && backOfQueue == NULL)
        return true;
}
template<class ItemType>
inline void LinkedQueue<ItemType>::enqueue(int key)
{
    QueueNode<ItemType>* ptr = new QueueNode();
    ptr->key = key;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (frontOfQueue == NULL)
    {
        frontOfQueue = ptr;
        backOfQueue = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        backOfQueue->next = ptr;
        backOfQueue = ptr;
    }
}
template<class ItemType>
inline void LinkedQueue<ItemType>::dequeue()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        std::cout << "ERROR: Queue is empty.\n";
    else if (frontOfQueue == backOfQueue)
    {
        free(frontOfQueue);
        frontOfQueue = NULL;
        backOfQueue = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        QueueNode<ItemType>* ptr = frontOfQueue;
        frontOfQueue = frontOfQueue->next;
        free(ptr);
    }
}
template<class ItemType>
inline void LinkedQueue<ItemType>::peekFront()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        std::cout << "ERROR: Queue is empty.\n";
    else 
        std::cout << frontOfQueue->key;
}
template<class ItemType>
inline void LinkedQueue<ItemType>::displayQueue()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        std::cout << "ERROR: Queue is empty.\n";
    else
    {
        QueueNode<ItemType>* ptr = frontOfQueue;
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << ptr->key << ", ";
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "LinkedQueue.h"
int main()
{
    LinkedQueue<int> queue;
    queue.enqueue(5);
    queue.enqueue(3);
    queue.enqueue(1);
    queue.peekFront();
    queue.displayQueue();
    queue.dequeue();
    queue.peekFront();
    queue.displayQueue();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011676/trying-to-create-new-instance-of-class-using-template-unexpected-error.

Comment: Unrelated: think on what's returned in `LinkedQueue<ItemType>::isEmpty` if `frontOfQueue == NULL && backOfQueue == NULL)` isn't `true`. When you have a `if` that decides whether or not to return `true` or `false`, ask yourself, "Do I need the `if (condition)` or can I just `return condition;`?"